# Pyspark dataframe join taking a very long time

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes in pyspark that I loaded from a hive database using 2 sparksql queries.

When I try to join the 2 dataframes using the `df1.join(df2,df1.id_1=df2.id_2)`, it takes a long time.
Does Spark re execute the sqls for df1 and df2 when I call the JOIN?

The underlying database is HIVE

Comment: Are you after a faster way to join the dataframes (in which case it might be helpful to elaborate more about your setup/data, what explain() says etc.), or is the question actually about "re-execution" of the sqls (in which case it would be helpful to be more specific about the code you have and what sqls you're referring to)

Answer (score -1):

Pyspark will be slower compared to using Scala as data serialization occurs between Python process and JVM, and work is done in Python.

Comment: That's not correct. With Hive as as source for `df1` and `df2`, `df1.join(df2,df1.id_1=df2.id_2)`, Python execution is limited to driver (which gives ~100 millisecond delay at worst).

Comment: Try and execute the same, using `spark-submit --master yarn-cluster...` once for pyspark and once for scala. You will notice the difference.